# pre-gzip css and js, or use deflate

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, gzip, deflate

Ever since a long time ago, I've been using a procedure that does the following:

- compare all css and js files against minified versions
- if no minified version exists, or minified version is older, they're (re)created (as *.css.min / *.js.min, respectively)
- when any minified css / js file is created, a .gzipped version is created (as *.cgz / *.jgz, respectively)
- my templating engine automatically adds the .min prefix to the css and js include calls
- .htaccess checks for a .cgz / .jgz version of the file, and adds the proper encoding rules accordingly

This has been working quite well, but I am wondering if it would be better to just minify the files, and use deflate to handle further compression. Here's my list of pro and cons, in the current arrangement:

**using gzip**

- Pro: less time spent compressing each css and js file on each page load
- Con: more processes in Rewrites
- Con: when files are being gzipped, the page load hangs a little bit

Obviously I am leaning toward deflate, but wanted to ask for some outside input on this.

For what it's worth, I am also using a highly effective caching policy.